# No site can be reached(ERR_TIMED_OUT) via browser other than chromium, even chromium's incognito mode

Tags: linux-mint, chrome, browser

In general, I use chromium. The other day I needed to check something using 'clear' browser, without any extensions running and figured chromium's `incognito mode` fits my needs. Under this mode, no page was loaded, all of them outputed

> this site can't be reached...ERR_TIMED_OUT'

after some time of load attempting.
'normal' chromium works without issues though.
Okay, no big deal, let's try another browser.
I've downloaded firefox from https://mozilla.org, unpacked it with `tar`, proceeded down to the firefox executive, launched it and received

> The connection has timed out

for several major sites(youtube, wikipedia, twitter, reddit).
Switched back to chromium and all of them load normally there.
Also remembered that I have 'vivaldi snapshot' installed, gave it a shot and got same results.
I use default firewall `ufw`, turning it off didn't resolve the issue.
So, what might be the problem? How can I fix it?

Troubleshooting info:
Browsers versions:
Chromium 77.0.3865.90
Vivaldi 1.16.1259.3
Mozilla Firefox 70.0.1

In order to facilitate troubleshooting, i've retrived logs this way:
Complete power off, power on, launch chromium, 'google' word 'test', launch incognito, same search, wait till error appears on the screen, launch firefox, same search and wait, closed firefox then chromium incognito, launch and search with vivaldi, turn off firewall, reboot, repeat 'probes' with disabled firewall, same results, retrive logs from current boot + previous one. 


[previous boot](https://pastebin.com/069iQahD)
[previous kernel](https://pastebin.com/7sQauJm4)
[current boot](https://pastebin.com/HXaNXLya)
[current kernel](https://pastebin.com/trnrNzkL)

Answer (score 0):

The other browsers and the "clear" Chromium might be missing some HTTP and/or HTTPS proxy settings that could be necessary for accessing internet at your site.

A network administrator can easily make it so that you must use a specific proxy to have any outside access at all... and in that case, the proxy will be able to log any IP address you browse to and any HTTP URLs you visit: "incognito mode" won't hide them from the proxy.

Comment: can I ask chromium configuration and network related questons here or should I proceed to another part of SE? If second, then which one?

Comment: I don't see any harm in asking, as the browsers you mentioned are commonly used in Linux/Unix systems. Worst case, someone flags the question and suggests a better location for it.